# After disposing async socket (.Net) callbacks still get called

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

I feel, that I am misunderstanding something about async sockets in .Net. The situation is as follows : I have 1 async socket client and 1 async socket server. They communicate without any visible problems, but when I close listener and disconnect clients, the "OnConnectRequest" which is bound to "BeginAccept" as a callback, still gets called at least once. The "BeginReceive", "OnConnectRequest", "Disconnect" and "Dispose" methods are :

```
  public void BeginReceive()
    {
        _listener.Bind(_endpoint);
        _listener.Listen(_maxConnections);
        try
        {
            _listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(OnConnectRequest), _listener);
        }
        catch (SocketException se)
        {
            OnListeningError(this, new Exception("Server cannot accept connections due to network shutdown or some fatal failure", se));
        }
    }



     protected void OnConnectRequest(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

        Socket client = listener.EndAccept(ar);
        var remoteEndpoint = client.RemoteEndPoint;

        IDuplexStateObject state = new DuplexStateObject();
        state.WorkSocket = client;

        if (_clients.Count <= _maxConnections)
        {
            lock (_clients)
            {
                _clients.Add(state);
            }

            OnConnected(this, state);
        }
        else
        {
            //denying connection
            client.Close();
            AcceptingError(this, null, new Exception(string.Format("Maximal connection count reached, connection attempt  {0} has been denied", (remoteEndpoint != null) ? remoteEndpoint.ToString() : null)));
        }

        //accept connections from other clients
        try
        {
            listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(OnConnectRequest), listener);
        }
        catch (SocketException se)
        {
            if (se.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.TooManyOpenSockets)
            {
                OnListeningError(this, new Exception("Maximal connection count reached, not possible to create any more connections"));
            }
            else
            {
                OnListeningError(this, new Exception("Server cannot accept connections due to network shutdown or some fatal failure"));
            }
        }
    }


         public void Disconnect(IStateObject state)
    {
        if (state.WorkSocket == null)
        {
            //OnDisconnectError(this, state.ClientInfo,
            //    new Exception("No underlying work socket found for client. Already disconnected, disposing connection..."));

            OnDisconnected(this, state.ClientInfo);
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            if (state.WorkSocket.Connected)
            {
                state.WorkSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            }
            state.WorkSocket.Close();
        }
        catch (SocketException se)
        {
            OnDisconnectError(this, state.ClientInfo, se);
        }
        OnDisconnected(this, state.ClientInfo); 
        lock (_clients)
        {
            _clients.Remove(state);
        }
    }

      public void Dispose()
    {
        _listener.Close();

        //keys are cloned before disconnecting
        foreach (var client in _clients.ToList())
        {
            Disconnect(client);
        }
    }
```

What I am doing is calling "Dispose" to closes listener and shut down all client sockets. The client is then still active, and it tries to reconnect, but what I expected to happen was server being completely unavailable on corresponding IP and port. What I see instead is "OnConnectRequest" callback being called, which crashes because of attempt to use already disposed socket. Can you please explain, what is wrong here, and how graceful shutdown of a listener and all accepted connections should look like ?

Comment: See samples on following webpage : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w89fhyex(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: why not using async/await?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is correct -- the callback you specify in a `Begin...` operation will *always* be called, even if you close the socket (if you close the socket, it will be called *because* of that). You should be catching the `ObjectDisposedException` you get on the `EndAccept` and then return without further action. Closing/disposing a socket/listener is the only way to cancel an asynchronous operation on it. (`EndAccept` can also produce `SocketException`, which should be handled normally.)

Using a flag you maintain yourself to check if the listener is still available is asking for trouble, because you're introducing shared state that needs to be synchronized (volatile reads and the like). You can easily introduce race conditions that way. The listener already maintains such a flag for you internally, which it uses to throw `ObjectDisposedException`, so I'd just use that. It's true that under normal circumstances catching `ObjectDisposedException` is a possible sign of a coding error (since you're supposed to know when an object is disposed), but with asynchronous code it's pretty standard.

Comment: Ok, so closing listener actually IS THE REASON why the callback is called. Thanks a lot!!  But besides catching ObjectDisposedException I can use some boolean variable (let say, "IsListening"), set it to false, when the listener is closed, and check its value inside the callback, right? Or in the world of async programming exceptions is a better choice?

Comment: I don't tjhink this is a good answer because now you cannot tell if you get the object disposed exception because of the intended graceful disconnect or because you actually had another error somewhere in your async function where you unintentionally used something that was disposed. This cannot be the production pattern. I know in C++ I'd keep track of the number of outstanding async IO ops issued and when disconnecting I'd call shutdown (making asyncsocket calls respond with their corresponding errors) then wait for the number of outstadning calls to hit 0 before destroying needed members.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz: you can use the exact same pattern in C#, if you like -- and yes, that will allow you to debug calls on an object disposed in a place where you didn't expect it to be disposed. Feel free to write it up as an answer. I've not been doing that over the past decade of .NET development, though -- the extra per-socket state management is a pain, and the intended benefit of allowing you to troubleshoot faulty code easier is not something I've felt a need for in practice.

Comment: I had written up a seperate question here that is more specifically about how to wait on the interlocked count, because, frankly, I don't know how to.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47311561/waiting-on-interlocked-0