# Waiting on Interlocked == 0?

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, synchronization, interlocked

Disclaimer: My C# isn't even close to as good as my C++

I am trying to learn how to do async sockets in C# in order to write a test app for a component of mine. My former attempts using TcpClient ended in failure and you can read the outstanding questions on that here:

[TcpClient.NetworkStream Async operations - Canceling / Disconnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47291661/tcpclient-networkstream-async-operations-canceling-disconnect?noredirect=1#comment81539534_47291661)

[Detect errors with NetworkStream.WriteAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47294295/detect-errors-with-networkstream-writeasync?noredirect=1#comment81545727_47294295)

Since, I could not get that working, I tried using Socket.BeginX and Socket.EndX instead. I got much further along. My problem now is that in the listing below, when it comes time to disconnect, which in turn calls shutdown and close on the socket, async operations are still outstanding and they will throw an object disposed exception or an object is set to null exception.

I found a similar post about that here:

[After disposing async socket (.Net) callbacks still get called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37135733/after-disposing-async-socket-net-callbacks-still-get-called)

However, I do not accept that answer, because if you are using exceptions for *intended* behavior, then 1) They are not exceptional 2) You cannot tell if the exception was thrown for your intended case or if it was thrown because you actually used a disposed object or a null reference in your async method, other than the socket.

In C++ with async socket code, I'd keep track of the number of outstanding async operations with Interlocked and when it came time to disconnect, I'd call shutdown, then wait for the interlocked to hit 0, and then close and destroy any members I needed to.

How would I go about waiting in my Disconnect method for all outstanding Async operations to complete in C# in the following listing?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using log4net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;

namespace IntegrationTests
{
    public class Client2
    {
        class ReceiveContext
        {
            public Socket    m_socket;
            public const int m_bufferSize = 1024;
            public byte[]    m_buffer = new byte[m_bufferSize];
        }

        private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger("root");

        static private ulong m_lastId = 1;

        private ulong  m_id;
        private string m_host;
        private uint   m_port;
        private uint   m_timeoutMilliseconds;
        private string m_clientId;
        private Socket m_socket;
        private uint   m_numOutstandingAsyncOps;

        public Client2(string host, uint port, string clientId, uint timeoutMilliseconds)
        {
            m_id                     = m_lastId++;
            m_host                   = host;
            m_port                   = port;
            m_clientId              = clientId;
            m_timeoutMilliseconds    = timeoutMilliseconds;
            m_socket                 = null;
            m_numOutstandingAsyncOps = 0;
        }

        ~Client2()
        {
            Disconnect();
        }

        public void Connect()
        {
            IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(m_host);
            IPAddress[] ipV4Addresses = ipHostInfo.AddressList.Where(x => x.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork).ToArray();
            IPAddress[] ipV6Addresses = ipHostInfo.AddressList.Where(x => x.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6).ToArray();
            IPEndPoint endpoint = new IPEndPoint(ipV4Addresses[0], (int)m_port);

            m_socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            m_socket.ReceiveTimeout = (int)m_timeoutMilliseconds;
            m_socket.SendTimeout    = (int)m_timeoutMilliseconds;

            try
            {
                m_socket.Connect(endpoint);

                log.Info(string.Format("Connected to: {0}", m_socket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString()));

                // Issue the next async receive
                ReceiveContext context = new ReceiveContext();
                context.m_socket = m_socket;
                m_socket.BeginReceive(context.m_buffer, 0, ReceiveContext.m_bufferSize, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), context);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // Error
                log.Error(string.Format("Client #{0} Exception caught OnConnect. Exception: {1}"
                                       , m_id, e.ToString()));
            }
        }

        public void Disconnect()
        {
            if (m_socket != null)
            {
                m_socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);

                // TODO - <--- Error here in the callbacks where they try to use the socket and it is disposed
                //        We need to wait here until all outstanding async operations complete
                //        Should we use Interlocked to keep track of them and wait on it somehow?
                m_socket.Close();
                m_socket = null;
            }
        }

        public void Login()
        {
            string loginRequest = string.Format("loginstuff{0})", m_clientId);
            var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(loginRequest);

            m_socket.BeginSend(data, 0, data.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(OnSend), m_socket);
        }

        public void MakeRequest(string thingy)
        {
            string message = string.Format("requeststuff{0}", thingy);
            var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

            m_socket.BeginSend(data, 0, data.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(OnSend), m_socket);
        }

        void OnReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
        {
            ReceiveContext context = (ReceiveContext)asyncResult.AsyncState;

            string data = null;
            try
            {
                int bytesReceived = context.m_socket.EndReceive(asyncResult);
                data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(context.m_buffer, 0, bytesReceived);

                ReceiveContext newContext = new ReceiveContext();
                newContext.m_socket = context.m_socket;

                m_socket.BeginReceive(newContext.m_buffer, 0, ReceiveContext.m_bufferSize, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), newContext);
            }
            catch(SocketException e)
            {
                if(e.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.ConnectionAborted) // Check if we disconnected on our end
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // Error
                log.Error(string.Format("Client #{0} Exception caught OnReceive. Exception: {1}"
                                       , m_id, e.ToString()));
            }
        }

        void OnSend(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
        {
            Socket socket = (Socket)asyncResult.AsyncState;

            try
            {
                int bytesSent = socket.EndSend(asyncResult);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                log.Error(string.Format("Client #{0} Exception caught OnSend. Exception: {1}"
                                       , m_id, e.ToString()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Main:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using log4net;
using log4net.Config;

namespace IntegrationTests
{
    class Program
    {
        private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger("root");

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                XmlConfigurator.Configure();
                log.Info("Starting Component Integration Tests...");

                Client2 client = new Client2("127.0.0.1", 24001, "MyClientId", 60000);
                client.Connect();
                client.Login();
                client.MakeRequest("StuffAndPuff");

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(60000); // Sim work until user shutsdown

                client.Disconnect();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                log.Error(string.Format("Caught an exception in main. Exception: {0}"
                                      , e.ToString()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

EDIT:

Here is my additional attempt using the answer proposed by Evk, to the best of my ability. It works fine as far as I can tell.

Problem with this is, that I feel like I basically made everything that was asynchronous into a synchronous call, because of the requirements to lock around anything that would change the counter or the state of the socket. Again, I am novice at C# compared to my C++, so please do point out if I completely missed the mark interpreting his answer.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace IntegrationTests
{
    public class Client
    {
        class ReceiveContext
        {
            public const int     _bufferSize    = 1024;
            public byte[]        _buffer        = new byte[_bufferSize]; // Contains bytes from one receive
            public StringBuilder _stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();   // Contains bytes for multiple receives in order to build message up to delim
        }

        private static readonly ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger("root");

        static private ulong _lastId = 1;
        private ulong  _id;

        protected string         _host;
        protected int            _port;
        protected int            _timeoutMilliseconds;
        protected string         _sessionId;
        protected Socket         _socket;
        protected object         _lockNumOutstandingAsyncOps;
        protected int            _numOutstandingAsyncOps;
        private bool             _disposed = false;

        public Client(string host, int port, string sessionId, int timeoutMilliseconds)
        {
            _id                         = _lastId++;
            _host                       = host;
            _port                       = port;
            _sessionId                  = sessionId;
            _timeoutMilliseconds        = timeoutMilliseconds;
            _socket                     = null;
            _numOutstandingAsyncOps     = 0;
            _lockNumOutstandingAsyncOps = new object();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if(_disposed)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (disposing)
            {
                _socket.Close();
            }

            _disposed = true;
        }

        public void Connect()
        {
            lock (_lockNumOutstandingAsyncOps)
            {
                IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(_host);
                IPAddress[] ipV4Addresses = ipHostInfo.AddressList.Where(x => x.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork).ToArray();
                IPAddress[] ipV6Addresses = ipHostInfo.AddressList.Where(x => x.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6).ToArray();
                IPEndPoint endpoint = new IPEndPoint(ipV4Addresses[0], _port);

                _socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                _socket.ReceiveTimeout = _timeoutMilliseconds;
                _socket.SendTimeout = _timeoutMilliseconds;

                try
                {
                    _socket.Connect(endpoint);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    // Error
                    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Client #{0} Exception caught OnConnect. Exception: {1}"
                                           , _id, e.ToString()));
                    return;
                }

                Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Client #{0} connected to: {1}", _id, _socket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString()));

                // Issue the first async receive
                ReceiveContext context = new ReceiveContext();

                ++_numOutstandingAsyncOps;
                _socket.BeginReceive(context._buffer, 0, ReceiveContext._bufferSize, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), context);
            }
        }

        public void Disconnect()
        {
            if (_socket != null)
            {
                // We need to wait here until all outstanding async operations complete
                // In order to avoid getting 'Object was disposed' exceptions in those async ops that use the socket
                lock(_lockNumOutstandingAsyncOps)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Client #{0} Disconnecting...", _id));

                    _socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);

                    while (_numOutstandingAsyncOps > 0)
                    {
                        Monitor.Wait(_lockNumOutstandingAsyncOps);
                    }

                    _socket.Close();
                    _socket = null;
                }
            }
        }

        public void Login()
        {
            lock (_lockNumOutstandingAsyncOps)
            {
                if (_socket != null && _socket.Connected)
                {
                    string loginRequest = string.Format("loginstuff{0}", _clientId);
                    var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(loginRequest);

                    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Client #{0} Sending Login Request: {1}"
                                           , _id, loginRequest));

                    ++_numOutstandingAsyncOps;
                    _socket.BeginSend(data, 0, data.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(OnSend), _socket);
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Client #{0} Login was called, but Socket is null or no longer connected."
                                           , _id));
                }
            }
        }

        public void MakeRequest(string thingy)
        {
            lock (_lockNumOutstandingAsyncOps)
            {
                if (_socket != null && _socket.Connected)
                {
                    string message = string.Format("requeststuff{0}", thingy);
                    var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

                    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Client #{0} Sending Request: {1}"
                                           , _id, message));

                    ++_numOutstandingAsyncOps;
                    _socket.BeginSend(data, 0, data.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(OnSend), _socket);
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Client #{0} MakeRequest was called, but Socket is null or no longer connected."
                                           , _id));
                }
            }
        }

        protected void OnReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
        {
            lock (_lockNumOutstandingAsyncOps)
            {
                ReceiveContext context = (ReceiveContext)asyncResult.AsyncState;

                string data = null;

                try
                {
                    int bytesReceived = _socket.EndReceive(asyncResult);
                    data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(context._buffer, 0, bytesReceived);

                    // If the remote host shuts down the Socket connection with the Shutdown method, and all available data has been received,
                    // the EndReceive method will complete immediately and return zero bytes
                    if (bytesReceived > 0)
                    {
                        StringBuilder stringBuilder = context._stringBuilder.Append(data);

                        int index = -1;
                        do
                        {
                            index = stringBuilder.ToString().IndexOf("#");
                            if (index != -1)
                            {
                                string message = stringBuilder.ToString().Substring(0, index + 1);
                                stringBuilder.Remove(0, index + 1);

                                Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Client #{0} Received Data: {1}"
                                                       , _id, message));
                            }
                        } while (index != -1);
                    }
                }
                catch (SocketException e)
                {
                    // Check if we disconnected on our end
                    if (e.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.ConnectionAborted)
                    {
                        // Ignore
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Error
                        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Client #{0} SocketException caught OnReceive. Exception: {1}"
                                               , _id, e.ToString()));
                        Disconnect();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    // Error
                    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Client #{0} Exception caught OnReceive. Exception: {1}"
                                           , _id, e.ToString()));
                    Disconnect();
                }
                finally
                {
                    --_numOutstandingAsyncOps;
                    Monitor.Pulse(_lockNumOutstandingAsyncOps);
                }
            }

            // Issue the next async receive
            lock (_lockNumOutstandingAsyncOps)
            {
                if (_socket != null && _socket.Connected)
                {
                    ++_numOutstandingAsyncOps;

                    ReceiveContext newContext = new ReceiveContext();
                    _socket.BeginReceive(newContext._buffer, 0, ReceiveContext._bufferSize, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), newContext);
                }
            }
        }

        protected void OnSend(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
        {
            lock (_lockNumOutstandingAsyncOps)
            {
                try
                {
                    int bytesSent = _socket.EndSend(asyncResult);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Client #{0} Exception caught OnSend. Exception: {1}"
                                           , _id, e.ToString()));
                    Disconnect();
                }
                finally
                {
                    --_numOutstandingAsyncOps;
                    Monitor.Pulse(_lockNumOutstandingAsyncOps);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that finalizers are for cleaning up unmanaged resources, not managed resources.  You shouldn't have a finalizer at all on your object.

Comment: [`CountdownEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.threading.countdownevent) is your friend.

Comment: To add to what Servy said, as you're from a C++ background, don't confuse C++ destructors with managed finalizers. The fact that C# borrowed the syntax and even uses the word "destructor" in some documentation is really quite unfortunate. `IDisposable` is what C# uses for deterministic cleanup, and finalizers are rarely needed (they're the final stopgap for releasing unmanaged resources when an object is garbage collected -- normally, such an object should already have had its `Dispose` called and the finalizer suppressed).

Comment: Regarding one objection: "you cannot tell if the exception was thrown for your intended case or if it was thrown because you actually used a disposed object or a null reference in your async method, other than the socket." The intent is that you *only* catch `ObjectDisposedException`, and *only* on the `Socket.EndReceive`. This throws `ObjectDisposedException` if and only if the socket has been closed. There should be no other statements in the block. If you wrap a bunch of stuff in a generic `catch (Exception)` and go around setting references to `null`, then yes, you have a problem.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Maybe, but CountdownEvent cannot start at 0, because it will then be considered signalled, which is fine, except that you cannot addcount after that. So, I don't know how I would use it. Here was my concept program for testing your suggestion: https://www.ideone.com/zfbJH9

Comment: Alright, I only briefly looked at `CountdownEvent`, to be honest -- I've never used it myself but it *looked* promising. I was sure they'd have a class for it by now. :-P The "natural" way to implement this in .NET is [with a monitor](https://www.ideone.com/PdJ3P1). Note that this solution is still not complete with regards to production code: you must ensure no async operations can be started after the socket has been slated to shut down, otherwise the count may never reach zero. It's exactly this kind of administration that I prefer to cut short by just closing the socket.

Comment: Fair enough. Just as an aside, I think it would be handy to know how many outstanding async ops I have anyway, so I can tell my service is getting bogged down. Hard to believe there is no sync mechanism that we can wait on notification, which checks a predicate, and continues to wait, like a CV in C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Monitor.Wait` and `Monitor.Pulse` for that:

```
static int _outstandingOperations;
static readonly object _lock = new object();
static void Main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        var tmp = i;
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            lock (_lock) {
                _outstandingOperations++;
            }
            // some work
            Thread.Sleep(new Random(tmp).Next(0, 5000));
            lock (_lock) {
                _outstandingOperations--;
                // notify condition might have changed
                Monitor.Pulse(_lock);
            }
        });
    }

    lock (_lock) {
        // condition check
        while (_outstandingOperations > 0)
            // will wait here until pulsed, lock will be released during wait
            Monitor.Wait(_lock);
    }
}
```

Comment: Going to edit original post with attempt at this and questions pertaining to it.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz you don't need to lock around whole operation like you did in your example, only around incrementing/decrementing field (like in my answer - I don't lock around thread sleep imitating work). You can move that to separate methods (IncAnynsOperations/DecAsyncOperations).

Comment: I locked only around increment and decrement of count and got the same old exceptions when disconnect was called, because the async methods were still in the middle of acting on the socket, so the socket state had to be locked as well.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz in code you provided you _first_ shutdown socket and only after that waiting for async operations to drop to 0. Of course that will not work. You have to first wait for them to drop to 0, then shutdown (preferrably indicating that shutdown is in progress with some flag so that you don't start more async operations after they have dropped to 0).

Comment: Yes, I think it needs some state tracking. Giving it a 3rd attempt today.

Comment: Gonna mark this as an answer, because it addresses my specific question. Thanks! I have a feeling I'll be working on the syncing on the socket code for while and probably have multiple questions I can make separate posts about. i.e I hope no one cuts and pastes the code thus far looking for a async client that works.